# SharePoint SPGridView client side available options

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I've been looking in to a few grids that are currently built that I could just make use of however none that I have found so far provide the same functionality as an SPGridView in terms of filtering.

The closest I've managed to find is JSGrid which allows you to search each individual column.

What I'd like to do is to display all unique values for a specific column in the filtering option below the normal Ascending and descending much like the list view functionality you currently get in a document library or list.

Many Thanks

Truez

Comment: you want unique value list as filter option on a single column in gridview, right?

Comment: Yeah so in each column I should be able to select a unique value